# COLLATE NOCASE on sqlite IN clauses

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is there a way to use a "IN" clause in SQLITE that will match the column to all elements in the in clause case in sensitively. I have  a query

```
select * from Table
where table.column in ("aaa", "bbb")
```

table.column has "AAA" and "BBB", this results in no rows selected. Ideally the solution should have the same result as the query IN is a shorthand for

```
select * from Table
where table.column = "aaa" or table.column = "bbb"
collate NOCASE
```

I have been suggested a workaround, which works but is not clean or satisfying

```
select * from Table
where upper(table.column) in (upper("aaa"), upper("bbb"))
```

Simple adding collate NOCASE on my "IN" query does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One method is:

```
select t.*
from Table t
where t.column collate NOCASE in ('aaa' collate NOCASE, 'bbb' collate NOCASE)
```

However, this can actually be shortened to:

```
select t.*
from Table t
where t.column collate NOCASE in ('aaa', 'bbb')
```

The collation for the column is used for the entire expression.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?  Putting the 'collate nocase' at the end of the statement (or anywhere else) didn't work, but this worked great.

Comment: @user117529 . . . https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#collateop.  An expression in this context means an expression that returns a string.